# Example code for using CBOR in Angular Frontend

Tags: angular, typescript, frontend, cbor

has anybody some example code about how to decode CBOR messages in an Angular Frontend?
If I install 'cbor-web' via npm I get an exception during startup of the Angular Frontend:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: process is not defined
    at Object.push.MCLT.exports.debuglog (util.js:100)
    at Object.481 (cbor.js:2)
    at o (cbor.js:2)
    at Object.830 (cbor.js:2)
    at o (cbor.js:2)
    at Object.20 (cbor.js:2)
    at o (cbor.js:2)
    at Object.141 (cbor.js:2)
    at o (cbor.js:2)
    at cbor.js:2
    at cbor.js:2
    at cbor.js:2
    at cbor.js:2
    at Object.4uv0 (cbor.js:2)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:79)
```

Thanks,
Dieter